# Get rid of "Can't find audio files" prompt in Logic Pro X

Tags: logic-pro

I have a project, and that everytime I open it, Logic warns me about some files it can't locate. I've searched my disk, and these files are gone. And I don't mind - all the sound I expect is in the project, so I suspect these belong to earlier takes or whatever.

Point is: Logic can't find some files and I don't really care. How can I tell Logic to stop looking for these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the [Project Audio Browser](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH24700?viewlocale=en_KW&locale=en_KW) (Audio Bin in Logic 9) and locate the problematic files (they should appear there even if they are missing). Once there remove them from the project, and that should do the trick.